# Vuetify Navigation Drawer and navbar in other component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am working with vuetify, and I have separated my navigation-drawer, v-app-bar and v-content and I want to run the @click of v-app-bar-nav (child) inside the parent v-navigation-drawer to hide or show the: `mini-variant.sync`.

MainComponent:

```html
<template>
    <v-sheet
            height="100%"
            class="overflow-hidden"
            style="position: relative;"
    >
          <v-content>
            <v-container fluid>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </v-container>
          </v-content>
            <v-footer class="justify-center pl-0"  inset app>
            <span>&copy; 2020</span>
        </v-footer>
        <navigation></navigation>
    </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
    import Navigation from '../backend/NavigationComponent'

export default {
        components:{
            navigation: Navigation
        }
}
</script>
```

NavigationComponente:

```html
<template>
    <v-sheet>
        <v-navigation-drawer
                v-model="drawer"
                enable-resize-watcher app dark
                :mini-variant.sync="mini"
                permanent
        >
            <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-avatar>
                    <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/78.jpg"></v-img>
                </v-list-item-avatar>

                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
    <navbar :mini="mini"></navbar>

    </v-sheet>
</template>

<script>
// Import NavBar
import Navbar from '../backend/NavbarComponent'
export default {
        components: {
            navbar: Navbar
        },
    
    data(){
        return {
            drawer: true,
            mini: true,
        }
    }
   
}
</script>
```

NavbarComponent:

```html
<template>
    <v-app-bar fixed app>
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="mini != mini"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
            <v-toolbar-title>Topics</v-toolbar-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-account-circle</v-icon>
            </v-btn>

        </v-app-bar>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
      mini: {
          default: true
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

I receive the property but when I do a method to send the value to the father I cannot change the status of "mini".

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: did you find any thing ?